# Doubt on Lemma II.5.3 Hartshorne

Tags: algebraic-geometry, quasicoherent-sheaves

I'm studying this lemma, and I do not understand the green boxed part, namely
$M_i:=M\otimes_B A_{g_i}$ is an $A_{g_i}-$module.
[image]

Comment: I’m not sure I understand what your issue is. Is your question “why is $M \otimes_B A_{g_i}$ an $A_{g_i}$-module”?

Comment: @Mindlack yes, that is! Is this because I can endow to $M\otimes_R N$ a $N-$module structure by $n\cdot(a\otimes b):=a\otimes (nb)$?

Comment: If your $N$ is a ring (as $A_g$ is), then yes. This is the typical extension by scalars technique.